# How to Calculating date in Java

Tags: java

I am a beginner of java. I need to calculate the date. If I the enter the duration and I select the starting date, the end date should automatically be calculated. I have done this in jQuery and it works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYy8y.)

this is the working code I tried in jQuery:

```
 $( "#start_date" ).change(function() {

        if($( "#duration" ).val()==""){
            return false;
        }
        var x = Number($( "#duration" ).val());


        var CurrentDate = new Date($("#start_date" ).val());
        CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + x);
        $("#end_date" ).val(CurrentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]);

    });
```

To select the date I used jDateChooser:

```java
int duration = Integer.parseInt(txtdur.getText()); 

Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat Date_Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date1 = Date_Format.format(txtdate.getDate());
```

after that I don't know how complete code

Comment: Your image is gone. Learn to use the image tool present on the toolbar when editing your Question.

Comment: Link to explain what is JDateChooser. I cannot find such a class bundled with Java.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

you should convert your date to instant and add the time you need.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Date;

/*...*/

public void setEndDate(int timeInHours){
    /* getting the start date */
    Date startDate = myJDateChooserStartDate.getDate();

    /* creating a new date */
    Date endDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    /* setting the start date to endDate */
    endDate.setTime(startDate.getTime());

    /* increasing the endDate */
    endDate = increaseTimeInHours(endDate, timeInHours);

    /* setting the end date to the component */
    myJDateChooserEndDate.setDate(endDate);
}

public static Date increaseTimeInHours(Date date, int hours) {

    return Date.from(date.toInstant().plus(Duration.ofHours(hours)));
}

/*...*/
```

Comment: sir how to pass in to the JDatechooser sir. if i select start date enddate should calucating according duration

Comment: String Duration = txtdur.getText();  i tried above code it won't work sir.according the Duration  enter calculating enddate

Comment: Use: int duration = Integer.valueOf(txtdur.getText());  and setEndDate(duration);  // don't forget replace your own JDateChooser components